# How to remove an erroneous item from g chart?

Tags: google-visualization

code below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {packages:['wordtree']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
          [ ['Phrases'],
            ['information technology'],
            ['web'],
            ['development']
          ]
        );

        var options = {
          wordtree: {
            format: 'implicit',
           // word: ''
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.WordTree(document.getElementById('wordtree_basic'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wordtree_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

issue:
expected three items to be rendered, however, we now have four including an erroneous "technology" while view source indicates correct rendering.

tested browser; firefox and chrome.

Comment: not sure that it is an error, rather just the chart's default algorithm. you could use the `wordSeparator` option to treat `'information technology'` as one word, or use an explicit word tree to control the outcome...

Comment: @WhiteHat good to know the "wordSeparator" option, after applying it, the "information technology" item is now showing up as "information tech...".  So, it seems that there's a default word length, how could we circumvent this problem?  Thanks.